# Passing variables through dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been able to pass in arguments to `dplyr` using .dots in combination with the _ variables. However this method does not seem to work here. I have searched other similar questions, but I haven't found a robust solution.

**WORKING EXAMPLE**

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

mtcars$brand<-row.names(mtcars)
mtcars_new<-mtcars %>%
   mutate(brand = strsplit(brand," ")) 

mtcars_new$brand<-sapply(mtcars_new$brand, "[", 1)
```

**Attempt to pass in variable -- Fails**

```
 target<-names(mtcars)[length(mtcars)]
 mtcars_new<-mtcars %>%
     mutate(target = strsplit(target," ")) 

 mtcars_new[length(mtcars)]<-sapply(mtcars_new[length(mtcars)], "[", 1)
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Wait, where are you using tidyr?

Comment: In function I am using, following the results of the mutate I use an unnest() to transform the results row by row

Comment: I still don’t understand how that’s relevant for the question here.

Comment: Instead of using the sapply, using an unnest() causes it to error. I believe unnest is just in tidyr and not dplyr? The unnest will work in the first example, but not in the second example -- I apologize if I was unclear. 

From my time spent debugging the unnest, it seems to function differently than dplyr in the way arguments/variables are passed to it... is that not true?

Comment: Would `library(lazyeval);mtcars %>% mutate_(interp(~sapply(strsplit(v, ' '),'[',1), v=as.name(target)))%>%select(-brand) %>% setNames(., c(head(names(mtcars),-1), target))` work for you.

Comment: I think you don't need `strsplit`, you can use `sub` i.e. `mtcars %>% mutate_(interp(~sub('\\s+.*', '', v), v=as.name(target))) %>% select(-brand) %>% setNames(., c(head(names(mtcars),-1), target))`

Comment: @akrun that worked, thank you! 

I apologize if my question was just dplyr related. I tried to edit my question further to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `interp` from `library(lazyeval)` to pass the variable.  Instead of `strsplit`, which return a `list`, we can use `sub` to remove the substring characters that begins with the first space to the end of the string, remove the 'brand' column and change the column names with `setNames`.

```
library(lazyeval)
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
    mutate_(v1=interp(~sub('\\s+.*$', '', v), v=as.name(target))) %>% 
    select_(.dots=setdiff(c(names(mtcars), 'v1'), target)) %>%
    setNames(., c(head(names(mtcars),-1), target))
```